# content navigator P8 stepprocessor property order

Tags: content-management-system, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

We have a FileNet 5.1 system with Content Navigator as the UI. From content navigator we use the default workflow stepprocessor to display workflow steps.

We use the IBM EDS service to add additional properties(like mandatory fieds) to these stepprocessors.

This service loads JSON files to augment the workflow fields.

I now have a question what determines the order of the property in how th content navigator/eds determines the fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is not possible to manipulate the property order out of the box. The solution: make a custom stepprocessor where you can manipulate it yourself.

Comment: Actually (If I got your question correctly) you can, just change the order of the properties in the JSON response returned by the EDS and the order would change. The EDS and even the Response Filter Plugin render the properties sequentially based on the order of the JSON retrieved from the back-end service.

Comment: Looking back at this, you are probably right, though now I would implement this using an actual response filter over EDS because response filters would provide a bit more flexibility as you can only have one eds instance per navigator instance as the url is set at plugin level. An actual response filter would have the benefit that it will be easier to have multiple desktops, and as you can select the plugins to load per desktop the various solutions will not bite each other.